# Смена пользователя через Skype4java

Tags: java

Сижу четвёртый час, ищу функцию смены(или, по крайней мере выхода\входа)аккаунта в библиотеке skype4java. Когда пытаюсь соединится со Skype, когда я не авторизован, приложение выдаёт exception. Это вообще возможно?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тому, что skype API закрыт (deprecated), только это и возможно.

Comment: А перевести на русский?

Comment: API skype4java больше не поддерживается и считается устаревшим

Comment: Да не, все остальные функции вроде работают.

Comment: А есть что нибудь не устаревшее для работы со Skype?